# Getting Error "Unknown MySQL server host" during importing the sql file?

Tags: mysql, mysql5.5

In mysql server, when importing the sql file into the db. I am getting as error as below. So, can you help where the issues lies that is in mysql server config or the sql file

ERROR 2005 (HY000) at line 1: Unknown MySQL server host 'Courier' (1)

Mysql Server Version : 5.0.45

Comment: Have you got an entry called 'Courier' in your hosts file? If not, try specifying the host in its IP equivalent

Comment: there is no entry with 'Courier' in your hosts file

Answer (score 1):

This is a name resolution issue. The machine you're using to import this sql file is not able to resolve the MySQL Server hostname 'Courier'.

Are you sure this is the correct hostname? Can you provide the output of a 'nslookup Courier' and the command you're using to import?

If you're not sure about the hostname, try importing using the MySQL Server ip address.

Hope this helps.